# Proof of a partition of $f(x) = x^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = x^2$. Find a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ so that $\overline{\sum}(P,f) - \underline{\sum}(P,f)<.001$.

I missed class the other day, but I'm assuming the overlined/underlined sigmas indicate right/lefthand Riemann sums, respectively. Correct me if that's not true.

Comment: Notations may vary, but I would have assumed they indicated upper and lower Riemann sums.  Of course in this example your function is increasing on $[0,1]$, so it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: If this is a real analysis class, then these most likely indicate upper and lower sums, which are distinct from Riemann sums in general. For future reference, put everything you want formatted with $\LaTeX$ inside a single pair of delimiters, i.e. treat the dollar signs as parentheses containing your math.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: using a partition into  equal-sized subintervals, all the terms of the two Riemann sums are the same except those for $x=0$ and $x=1$, which makes it easy to find the difference.

Comment: @Robert_Israel I don't understand how the terms of the Riemann sums are the same. Shouldn't every term in the lefthand be smaller than the righthand?

Comment: The first term of one is the second term of the other.

Comment: so then shouldn't the difference of the two sums be the farthest right minus the farthest left? so you're suggesting I just take a partition where that <.001.

Comment: You've got it...